# diffrence betweeen Doctrine 1.0.7 and Doctrine 2.0?

Tags: php, doctrine

In my old project we are using Doctrine 1.0.

Now changing to the Doctrine 2.0. What is the difference? now effected on old doctrine queries.

Which php, Apache, mysql versions are supported by Doctrine 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2.0 changed a lot of stuff. A lot. You'll have to change almost everything related to Doctrine in your project. It's not a painless transition.

As for requirements, you'll need PHP 5.3.0 to run Doctrine 2.

Comment: thanku for u r replay.You mean nothing will be effected old doctrine queries.yes?

Comment: You'll have to make them again.

Comment: You'll have to code the queries again, Ikon. And adapt many other areas of your code. So, to be honest, throw Doctrine 1.x code away and implement Doctrine 2. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a completely new ORM and you will need to learn this new framework without reuse your previous queries and models.

But this is a faster and better structured framework, and I'm sure that is worth.

Comment: As said, Doctrine 2 is a complete rewrite of D1. Depending on your Project, changing to D2 can make big trouble (have been there before). If you're working on anything that has to do with RIA, JSON or AJAX - try to avoid Doctrine.